# Does this explanation hold good even in case of Mitotracker red?

Tags: cell-biology, physiology, mitochondria, membrane

When the fluorescence intensity is higher when the depolarization is high?
The more damage to the mitochondria, the more mitochondrial dysfunction and therefore more fluorescence intensity. So, in irradiated cells(), 2, 5, 20Gy); the Mitotracker Fluorescence intensity will be lowest in 0GY and highest in 10 gy.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Mitotracker probes accumulate in active mitochondria, not in ones that are dysfunctional, as mentioned in the [product page](https://www.cellsignal.com/products/buffers-dyes/mitotracker-red-cmxros/9082?_requestid=1699945) from Cell Signalling Technologies (emphasis mine):

> ...with MitoTracker® probes, which passively diffuse across the plasma membrane and **accumulate in active mitochondria**.